# onComplete method is not called on htc desire

Tags: android, facebook, authorization

I am implementing a Facebook login facility on Android which seems to work OK on the emulator and on Google Nexus device. However the authorization seems to be cancelled by the user on HTC Desire S and so the `onComplete()` is never called. The only difference I found is that HTC has a built in facebook application. This is the code I am using:

```
private void Login(){
    facebook.authorize(this,new String[] {"email"}, new Facebook.DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Log.d("Auth","onCompleteCalled");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("Auth","Cancelled");

        }
    });
```

The error message comes from this section of Facebook SDK code:

```
} else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

            // An Android error occured.
            if (data != null) {
                Log.d("Facebook-authorize",
                        "Login failed: " + data.getStringExtra("error"));
                mAuthDialogListener.onError(
                        new DialogError(
                                data.getStringExtra("error"),
                                data.getIntExtra("error_code", -1),
                                data.getStringExtra("failing_url")));

            // User pressed the 'back' button.
            } else {
                Log.d("Facebook-authorize", "Login canceled by user."); //This is the error I get
                mAuthDialogListener.onCancel();
            }
```

Comment: What version of the Facebook app and what Android version do you have on your desire? I have just tested that with a 2.2. desire (which comes with Facebook for Android 1.3.2) and it works for me (falls back to the web authentication though). Also note that you can update the facebook app from the market, so chances are the users have the most recent version instead of the inbuild anyway.

Comment: Facebook version 1.5.1, Htc Android version 2.3.3. My app is created on 2.1 version though. I also have Facebook for HTC Sense version 1 which I cannot unistall either.

Comment: mFacebook.authorize(context,
                new String[] { "user_photos", "friends_photos", "publish_stream" },
                -1, 
                (DialogListener) dialogListener);

"-1" did the job, calling the traditional dialog box instead of the new integrated login dialogbox. If anyone's got any better solution I would be glad to hear it. 
Credits to Shane Oliver

Comment: @JustCurious thanks for this last comment which solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please Update below code of your application, it will solve your problem.

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            new LoginDialogListener());
}
```